# Write a variable content in xml

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Here is my problem: i want to put my variable (a SQL database serialized) in my xml file but only the 36 first characters are written.
When I write all the text it works.

Here the code  php:

```
public function createCache($coucou)
{
    $xml = new \DOMDocument;
    $xml->load(__DIR__.'/../../tmp/cache/datas/'.$this->typeData.'.xml');
    $xml->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->textContent='';

    $text = serialize($coucou);

    $xml->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->textContent=$text;


    $xml->save(__DIR__.'/../../tmp/cache/datas/'.$this->typeData.'.xml');
}
```

And my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cache>
    <content>a:2:{i:0;O:11:"Entity\News":7:{s:9:"</content>
</cache>
```

For the information here is the value of `$text`

```
:a:2:{i:0;O:11:"Entity\News":7:{s:9:"*auteur";s:16:"LE grand manitou";s:8:"*titre";s:15:"C'est moiiiiiii";s:10:"*contenu";s:34:"ça fonctionnne!c'est genial!!!! ";s:12:"*dateAjout";s:19:"2018-08-25 11:19:11";s:12:"*dateModif";s:19:"2018-08-25 11:19:11";s:10:"*erreurs";a:0:{}s:5:"*id";s:1:"2";}i:1;O:11:"Entity\News":7:{s:9:"*auteur";s:6:"Pierre";s:8:"*titre";s:6:"Coucou";s:10:"*contenu";s:15:"Je fais un test";s:12:"*dateAjout";s:19:"2018-08-25 00:00:00";s:12:"*dateModif";s:19:"2018-08-25 00:00:00";s:10:"*erreurs";a:0:{}s:5:"*id";s:1:"1";}}
```

Comment: I don't understand. *but only the 36 first characteres are written. When i write all the text it works*? Do you mean that when using the variable `$text`, only 36 characters are written, but if you use a string assignment it works?

Comment: @BenM yes it works i tried and it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 80% certain this is your problem:

PHP's `serialize()` does not return ASCII or UTF-8 strings. It's a binary format, and you cannot embed it into text formats like XML or JSON. Don't do this.

The reason is that it uses things like `0x00` to denote certain things like private and protected properties.

I'm guessing that the DOM sees a non-ascii character and 'gives up'. You don't see it when you're outputting the string, because these bytes typically don't show up in browsers or terminals.

Using PHP's `serialize()` format is kind of a bad idea anyway... but since it kind of looks like you're using it as some caching mechanism on a filesystem, why would you embed it in XML? Just store the serialized string by itself. It's faster because you don't need an XML parser.

Comment: thanks ! i didn't know that, i thought about that and try to encode the variable in UTF-8 and it didn't worked so do you know how i can resolve the problem?

Comment: You are 100% correct - _Object's private members have the class name prepended to the member name; protected members have a '*' prepended to the member name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side._